# Download PowerBI embed as PDF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, powerbi

I have a requirement to download powerBI embedded as a PDF file.
I tried Kendo UI script to download web pages (to be specific, anything inside a div is converted and downloaded as PDF).
I tried accessing divs inside PowerBi Embed reports on a ASPX web page using jQuery. PowerBi Embedded report is rendered inside an iframe. I am always getting content document of Powerbi report iframe as NULL. Possible cause is CORS restrictions.
Is there any way to download the Report as PDF?

Comment: Have you tried Javascript API to embed you PowerBI app?

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported with the new API released in March 2020

There are two available API endpoints

**1: [Export to File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile)**

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo
```

**2: [Export File in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofileingroup)**

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo
```

Note: 
Both require a request body with the following:

```
| Name   | Required | Type           | Description           |
|--------|----------|----------------|-----------------------|
| format | True     | FileFormat     | Export to file format |
```

**[FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofileingroup#fileformat)**

```
| Name  | Type   |
|-------|--------|
| CSV   | string |
| DOCX  | string |
| IMAGE | string |
| HTML  | string |
| PDF   | string |
| PNG   | string |
| PPTX  | string |
| XLSX  | string |
| XML   | string |
```

Answer (score 1):

yes! power BI add this feature with there august 2018 release.

[image: Export to PDF]

```
select File > Export to PDF from Power BI Deskop.
```

**Note**
The feature does export custom visuals, but it does not export any wallpaper you may have applied to the report.